# I can't get 256 colours to work with Vim in iTerm2 on MacOS X

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, macos

I am having a rough time getting the colors right with my vim setup and the color scheme I want to use.

Using:

- OSX 10.10.2
- Vim 7.4
- iTerm2 (Set to report terminal type as "xterm-256color")
- [gruvbox theme](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox)
- Using the [gruvbox provided osx script](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Terminal-specific#a-recommended-256-color-gruvbox-palette-shellscript) to adjust color
- Have tried adjusting the `set t_Co=256` setting in my vimrc

Not matter what I have tried, the comment highlighting in my editor [looks like the screenshot of  they show as an example what it should NOT look like.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/26c7f6f2495059d00675afe881d2e4709f0801ad/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f323331343037342f313236323431302f37326165323337362d326333652d313165332d383330622d3063363235376434656462362e706e67)

However - I did try download MacVim, and that worked just fine, but I am NOT interested in using MacVim, so please don't suggest that.

Comment: In iTerm, what does `echo $TERM` output? Additionally, you might want to check what `:hi Comment` says, particularly about the cterm setting. It might be setting italics when iTerm does not have support for italics (well it does but lets just assume it doesn't, because the solution is quite hacky)

Comment: Also, do not manually set `t_Co`. Vim is quite capable of reading the $TERM variable to see if the terminal does support 256colors. Manually setting it will break havoc (okay I exaggerate a bit) if the Terminal does not support 256 colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like gruvbox sets italic on by default for the Comment syntax group if you're running terminal vim, which is a big problem if the terminal does not support italics. iTerm does but you have to get a specific termcap to enable it.

But it looks gruvbox recently fixed this [issue](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/pull/47). So, simply update your gruvbox colorscheme and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: Yep - looks like the update fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to read [this blog post](https://alexpearce.me/2014/05/italics-in-iterm2-vim-tmux/), it explains how to add italic fonts to iterm2, tmux and vim.

Changing iterm2 .terminfo, worked like a charm for me.